# is it guaranteed that Dictionary.Values returns elements in the order they were added?

Tags: c#, dictionary

During review of code of one application i've found that it assumes that order of `Dictionary.Values` is the same as elements were added to collection.

I've wrote application to test if this true:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> values = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            values.Add("apple2", 2);
            values.Add("apple3", 3);
            values.Add("apple4", 4);
            values.Add("apple5", 5);
            values.Add("apple6", 6);
            values.Add("apple1", 1);

            var list = new List<int>(values.Values);

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And output is:

```
2
3
4
5
6
1
```

First of all I wonder how is that possible. Isn't Dictionary supposed to use unordered Tree or something like that?

Moreover MSDN states that:

> The order of the values in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated keys in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` returned by the Keys property.

So why MSDN tells that "order is unspecified" but implementation happens to keep order? Am I correct that I'm better not to rely on that fact?

Comment: It says that `ValueCollection` is in the same order as `KeyCollection`... but you don't know what order `KeyCollection` is in (i.e. you don't know if it's the same order as how they were inserted).

In other words if you insert:
(1,a), (2,b), (3,c)

the spec only says that if `KeyCollection` returns (2,3,1) then `ValueCollection` will return (b,c,a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I correct that I'm better not to rely on that fact?

Absolutely. Just because *sometimes* it keeps the order doesn't mean that either it will in future implementations, or indeed that it will do in all cases right now.

When the internal data structure is resized or if items are deleted, the order can change.

For example, if you add this code before you construct the list:

```
values.Remove("apple4");
values.Add("jon", 10);
```

on my box, I see the value 10 come where 4 was before... even though it was added *after* the entries for 5, 6 and 1.

You should *definitely, definitely* not rely on the ordering.

Comment: thanks Jon. I spent time to understand how such code works, then to write a test so after all I've decided that people just can't write code like that (well why someone decided that order will be kept?), and I've decided that probably i'm missing something...

Comment: @javapowered: I'm not quite sure I parsed your comment correctly, but it sounds like you're not missing anything - you really, really shouldn't rely on the ordering, and if there's code which does, you should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the values in order by chance could be due to your data that appears to be in order. Change the elements for mixed order and add remove the element the its order would be changed. You can not rely on the order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that behaviour then you should use an explicit ordered dictionary.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx